# Python regex - faster search

Tags: python, regex

I need a way to optimize by regex, here is the string I am working with:

```
rr='JA=3262SGF432643;KL=ASDF43TQ;ME=FQEWF43344;JA=4355FF;PE=FDSDFHSDF;EB=SFGDASDSD;JA=THISONE;IH=42DFG43;'
```

and i want to take only `JA=4355FF` which is before `JA=THISONE`, so i did it this way:

```
aa='.*JA=([^.]*)JA=THISONE[^.]*'
aa=re.compile(aa)
print (re.findall(aa,rr))
```

and i get:

```
['4355FF;PE=FDSDFHSDF;EB=SFGDASDSD;']
```

My first problem is slow searching apropriete part of string (becouse the string which i want to search is too large and usually `JA=THISONE` is at the end of string)

And second problem is i dont get `4355FF` but all string until `JA=THISONE`.

Can someone help me optimize my regex? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I. Consider using string search instead of regexes:

```
thisone_pos = rr.find('JA=THISONE')
range_start = rr.rfind("JA=", 0, thisone_pos) + 3
range_end = rr.find(';', range_start)
print rr[range_start:range_end]
```

II. Consider flipping the string and constructing your regex in reverse:

```
re.findall(pattern, rr[::-1])
```

Comment: Can you give me solution with using string search on this example, key thing here for me is that i only take JA='4355FF' which is before JA=THISONE

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the following solution:

```
import re

rr='JA=3262SGF432643;KL=ASDF43TQ;ME=FQEWF43344;JA=4355FF;PE=FDSDFHSDF;EB=SFGDASDSD;JA=THISONE;IH=42DFG43;'

m = re.findall( r"(JA=[^;]+;)", rr )

# Print all hits
print m

# Print the hit preceding "JA=THISONE;"
print m[ m.index( "JA=THISONE;" ) - 1]
```

First, you look for all instances starting with "JA;" and then, you pick the last instance located before "JA=THISONE;".